# Clear a Data Extension with a Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I am using a Data Extension to capture details collected from a website. Each day I have a Query Activity which moves the data captured to another Data Extension. I want to then clear the original Data Extension so it starts a fresh for the day.

How can I easily do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could probably achieve this by creating a SQL Query and set it to overwrite the Data Extension you wish to clear by doing the following

```
SELECT *
FROM DataExtension
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Run this step after you move the data you have captured.

Comment: Thanks @christopher that makes sense i will give that a go and let you know

Comment: @AndrewC no problem, let me know how you go

Comment: "WHERE 1 = 0" works without having to spend clock cycles thinking of a value that doesn't match.

Comment: @AndrewMcLeod your right, I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @chrisopher i just created a DE with 1 column in it to use and then all works well.

Comment: @AndrewC your welcome

Answer (score 5):

You can actually do this without selecting any rows from an existing Data Extension -- as long as you supply required columns in your target.  You can just set those column values to null:

```
select
null as Emailaddress
where 0 = 1
```

Comment: This is by far my favorite :-)

Answer (score 2):

When setting up to the query activity, set it to "over write".

[image]

This assumes that you are running this once a day...you wouldnt wanna over write it might day.

For more info:

- [SQL Actvities](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/)